# Example of a point that is not a Lebesgue point.

Tags: real-analysis

I learned about Lebesgue points which are points $x$ such that

$$\lim\limits_{r\to 0} \frac{1}{\lvert B(x,r)\rvert}\int_{B(x,r)}\lvert f(y)-f(x) \rvert dy=0$$

On wikipedia, they say that Lebesgue points are points that don't oscillate too much. So I am trying to find an example that is not a Lebesgue point. Let $f(x)=\sin {1 \over x}$ if $x\neq 0$. Is this Lebesgue integrable on $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$? Then how to show

$$\lim\limits_{r\to 0} \frac{1}{2\epsilon}\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}\lvert \sin {1 \over y} \rvert dy=0$$?

Comment: Your last equation is not related to the definition of a Lebesgue point.

Comment: Change variables $u=1/y$ and show that the integral is at least $c\epsilon$ so the limit is non zero; the function is bounded so it is integrable

Comment: If I do a change of variable I get $\int_{-1/\epsilon}^{1/\epsilon}\lvert \frac{sin(x)}{x}\rvert dx$. Then I have to show that the integrand  is bigger than $c\epsilon$? Is this true since the bounds of the integral go to infinity?

Comment: Let $f=1_{ \{ 0 \} }$, then the above limit is one at $x=0$.

Comment: Nice and easy example. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, notice that for $t\in [\pi/4 + n\pi, 3 \pi/4 + n \pi]$ we have $|\sin t|\ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. Therefore, on the interval $[\frac{1}{3\pi/4 + n \pi}, \frac{1}{\pi/4 + n \pi}]$  we have $|\sin \frac{1}{x}|\ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. We conclude
$$\int_0^{\frac{1}{\pi/4 + n \pi}} |\sin \frac{1}{x}| \ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sum_{k\ge n} ( \frac{1}{\pi/4 + k \pi}-\frac{1}{3\pi/4 + k\pi})$$

It is not very hard to see that the sum is larger than $\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{\pi/4 + n \pi}$. This shows that $0$ is not a Lebesgue point.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I was about to ask this question (with the less than instead of larger)